# View dragging segue

Tags: iphone, storyboard, drag, segue

I want to create an application, which displays a draggable window (cart). The cart has to be dragged from the bottom of the screen and must cover all opened views. The dragging must follow your finger.

Is it possible to implement this using segues? My idea is to perform the segue with the touch event like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Cart" sender:self];
```

The segue implementation then would open the cart, place it offscreen then position it to reflect the movement of user's finger until the user releases it. Then it would animate either back or to the full screen.

It segues are not meant for this, then how can I implement it?

EDIT:
I see, I have to be more specific :) If I understand the documentation well, I have three ways of presenting one view:

1. pushing it to a navigationController: I don't want this, because the cart exists "above" my navigation chains, so pushing it there wolud confuse users.
2. presenting it modally: You cannot drag the view, because the objects behind it are not displayed (they are just black).
3. adding the view to some other view, like the root navigationController of my app: tried this, but when I clicked some button on my cart, the app crashed. I believe, that it is because I have not initialized or stored the controller well.

So, let's say I can present the view modally. But how can I solve, that the presenting touch casuse moving of the window too? Where is this view ideally placed, to which object?

Answer (score 1):

from apple docs:

"Creating Custom Segues

Interface Builder provides segues for all of the standard ways to transition from one view controller to another..."

so if you want to move a view (not a view controller) by the movement of the finger segues are not for you..

inorder to make a view move by the movement of a finger this is what you should do:

add a pan gesture recognizer to your view (which we'll call theView):

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewPanned:)];
    [theView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

then implement the viewPanned: method

```
- (void)viewPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        theView.center = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
 }
```

notice that this code assumes that theView is added directly to the viewControllers.view (where self refers to the viewController)